# Is there a way to get an Excel doc that uses a visual basic feature to show in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, vba

[image: First image shows the blue filled in date sections in the Excel doc. This is the desired display format of the doc.]

[image: Second image shows what is displayed in SharePoint. No blue date sections. How can I get SharePoint to display this image to look like the above?].com/GNU92.png

First image shows the blue filled in date sections in the Excel doc. This is the desired display format of the doc.

Second image shows what is displayed in SharePoint. No blue date sections. How can I get SharePoint to display this image to look like the above?

I am trying to set up a editable Excel doc that also displays on a SharePoint page. The Excel document is using a Visual Basic feature that is a requirement. It is required that the file is only to be viewed by certain users and they are not allowed to download the Excel doc. I have the excel doc hidden via permissions and the Excel is also locked from editing.

SharePoint isn't displaying Excel Visual Basic feature. How can I make it do this?

Comment: I take it that the excel document is being accessed via office web apps then? (i.e. through your browser?)

Comment: Hi Roland. It is being accessed via the web apps. The 2nd of the above image is an Excel online web access web part and it is linked via a file location.

Answer (score 0):

Macro enabled workbooks can be opened in the web viewer, but their contents are not executed. You may need to explore using or building an Office Add-In for this visualization.

> **Workbook file formats that are supported in a browser window**
>
> Workbooks in any of the following file formats can be viewed in a
>   browser window:
>
> - Excel workbook (.xlsx)
> - Excel binary workbook file (xlsb)
> - OpenDocument Spreadsheet file (.ods)
> - Excel macro-enabled workbook (.xlsm)
>
>   - A workbook in this format can be opened but macros do not run in a browser window.
>
> Excel 97- Excel 2003 Workbook (.xls) or Excel 97- Excel 2003 Template
>   (.xlt) If a workbook is in .xls or .xlt format, you can typically view
>   but not edit a workbook in a browser window. When the file is edited,
>   it is saved in .xlsx or .xltx format.

[Differences between using a workbook in the browser and in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6?CorrelationId=4f7cb55b-9f17-486b-aca6-e3dde9d0492c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Hi Zach, thank you for your answer. So on further investigation and with reading the doc you linked my Excel .xlsm file will not load any macro in browser. I am unsure if what is creating the "blue sections" is a macro but do you know if there is a way to save the file so it displays, the file does not have to be edited online. Thanks again.

Comment: If it's a VBA marco generating the bars, you could to save the output as an image or PDF. You could also experiment with alternate ways to display a Gantt chart in Excel.